# Wordpress add_rewrite_rule for custom post type how to set correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

i have a custom post type for my wp blog called 'rules_and_laws' and I have added a function to specify a rewrite rule:

```
 function custom_rules_and_laws_permalink_structure() {
     add_rewrite_rule(
         '([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?rules_and_laws=$matches[1]',
        'top'
        );
 }
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rules_and_laws_permalink_structure' );
```

The rule works ok for custom post type 'rules_and_law', the only problem is that now all the other pages and posts of the blog return 404.

I tried another approach trying to apply the rewrite url only for cpt 'rules_and_laws' but nothing worked:

```
function custom_rules_and_laws_permalink_structure() {
    // Check if the current post type is 'rules_and_laws'
    if (is_singular('rules_and_laws')) {
        add_rewrite_rule(
            '([^/]+)/?$',
            'index.php?rules_and_laws=$matches[1]',
            'top'
        );
        flush_rewrite_rules(); // Flush the rewrite rules to apply the changes
    }
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rules_and_laws_permalink_structure');
```

for example with this code the rules was not applied at all ( looks like is_singular('rules_and_laws') don't work ).

This is an example of base url:

https://website.com?rules_and_laws=art-4-security-regulation

and that's the rewrite:

https://website.com/art-4-security-regulation

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an updated version of your code that should address the issue:

```
function custom_rules_and_laws_permalink_structure() {
    // Register the rewrite rule only for the 'rules_and_laws' post type
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^rules_and_laws/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?rules_and_laws=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );

    // Flush the rewrite rules to apply the changes
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rules_and_laws_permalink_structure');
```

Comment: Hi, Heidar Ammarloo!

You posted 9 answers in June that appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT), with *five* of these having comments that said that the answer didn't work. Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.